# how to get dropped element ID , dragDrop Angular

Tags: html, angular, drag-and-drop

> **i use this function on drop from task planned into task progress**

```
onDrop1(event:CdkDragDrop<string[]>,id:any){
      console.log('ondrop progress')
      this.updateProgress()
      if(event.previousContainer===event.container){
        
      moveItemInArray(
        event.container.data,
        event.previousIndex,
        event.currentIndex
    
      );
      }else{
        transferArrayItem(
          event.previousContainer.data,
          event.container.data,
          event.previousIndex,
          event.currentIndex,

        );
      }
       }
```

> **and this is the HTML code**

```
<h1>planned</h1>
<div  cdkDropList id="tasks_planned" [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="['tasks_progress']" (cdkDropListDropped)="onDrop($event)" 
  [cdkDropListData]="tasks_planned">
  <div cdkDrag class="drag-item"  *ngFor="let tache of tasks_planned">
    {{tache.description}}
  </div>
</div>
<h1>progress</h1>
<div cdkDropList id="tasks_progress" [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="['tasks_completed']" (cdkDropListDropped)="onDrop1($event,5)" 
  [cdkDropListData]="tasks_progress">
  <div cdkDrag class="drag-item" *ngFor="let tachep of tasks_progress" cdkDrag [cdkDragData]="tachep.id">
    {{tachep.description}}
  </div>
</div>
```

so i want to get the id of the element , to be draged

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In onDrop1(event) you has:event.previousContainer.data: the "cdkDropListData" of element you're draggind, event.container.data:the "cdkDropListData" of element where you dropped, event.previousIndex, the "index" of the element you're dragging and event.currentIndex, the "index" of element where you dropped. Imagine that `event.previousContainer.data[event.previousIndex]` or `event.container.data[event.currentIndex]` is the data you're looking for. Use a console.log to check it